# Why Xampp server allow open not existing path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server, xampp

I have a problem with xampp etc. When I typing in URL address, for example, http://localhost/project/index.php/whatever.php server opened index.php with crashed style instead Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server or something like that because /whatever.php does not exist in the project.

In console showed:
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/project/index.php/style/style.css".

How I can prevent the open not existing path from my project ?

Comment: Why do you reference non-existing paths in the first place? Why not avoid this?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Comment: @NicoHaase because people using the site may enter this address by mistake

Comment: See you my answer, should solve your issue, a lot of time ago I had the same problem and I solved as you can read in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

All versions of Apache allow this, it's normal... To solve your issue, please, edit your `httpd.conf` and where you have your `VirtualHost` config add this line:

`AcceptPathInfo Off`

Like here:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
  ServerName localhost:80
  ServerAlias localhost
  ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/localhost-error.log"
  TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/localhost-access.log"
  DocumentRoot "D:/Web/www"
    <Directory "D:/Web/www">
      Require all granted
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AcceptPathInfo Off
      AllowOverride All
      <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If not enough add this line to your `.htaccess`

```
################################################################################
######################### Remove /index.php/ from URLs #########################
################################################################################
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php(/.*) $1
```

Hope this helps.